Having any pubkey as signer for a function
I am trying to learn Anchor Solana.
I am trying to create a simple crud program and so far I have a code liek this:
#![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("coUnmi3oBUtwtd9fjeAvSsJssXh5A5xyPbhpewyzRVF");

#[program]
pub mod crud {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_database(ctx: Context<CreateDatabase>, name: String, data: String) -> Result<()> {
        let database = &mut ctx.accounts.database;
        database.owner = ctx.accounts.owner.key();
        database.name = name;
        database.data.push(data);
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_database(ctx: Context<UpdateDatabase>, _name: String, data1: String) -> Result<()> {
        let database = &mut ctx.accounts.database;
        database.data.push(data1);
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_by_any(ctx: Context<UpdateByAny>, _name: String, data1: String) -> Result<()> {
        let database = &mut ctx.accounts.database;
        database.data.push(data1);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct MyDatabase {
  pub owner: Pubkey,
  #[max_len(32)]
  pub name: String,
  #[max_len(5, 100)]
  pub data: Vec<String>,   
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(name: String)]
pub struct CreateDatabase<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
      init, 
      payer = owner, 
      space = 8 + MyDatabase::INIT_SPACE, 
      seeds = [b"database", owner.key().as_ref(), name.as_ref()], 
      bump
    )]
    pub database: Account<'info, MyDatabase>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(name: String)]
pub struct UpdateDatabase<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
      mut,
      seeds = [b"database", owner.key().as_ref(), name.as_ref()], 
      bump,
      realloc = 8 + MyDatabase::INIT_SPACE,
      realloc::payer = owner,
      realloc::zero = true
    )]
    pub database: Account<'info, MyDatabase>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(name: String)]
pub struct UpdateByAny<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
      mut,
      seeds = [b"database", owner.key().as_ref(), name.as_ref()], 
      bump,
      realloc = 8 + MyDatabase::INIT_SPACE,
      realloc::payer = signer,
      realloc::zero = true
    )]
    pub database: Account<'info, MyDatabase>,

    /// CHECK: The owner is stored for reference purposes. Permissions check ensures safety.
    pub owner: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

As you can see, while UpdateDatabase is signed by owner of the database, the UpdateByAny function is supposed to allow any signer edit the database.
I have created the corresponding test like this:
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor'
import {Program} from '@coral-xyz/anchor'
import {Keypair, PublicKey} from '@solana/web3.js'
import { BankrunProvider } from 'anchor-bankrun'
import {startAnchor} from 'solana-bankrun'
import {Crud} from '../target/types/crud'

const IDL = require('../target/idl/crud.json')

describe('crud', () => {
  const name = "db"
  const data = "data"
  const data2 = "data2"

  let context: any;
  let provider: any
  let program: any
  let payer: Keypair
  let newKeypair: Keypair
  let newPublicKey: PublicKey
  let createPDA: PublicKey
  let tx: any

  beforeAll(async () => {
    context = await startAnchor("", [{name: "crud", programId: new PublicKey(IDL.address)}], []);

    provider = new BankrunProvider(context);
    anchor.setProvider(provider);
    program = new Program<Crud>(IDL, provider);
    payer = provider.wallet.payer;

    newKeypair = Keypair.generate();
    newPublicKey = newKeypair.publicKey;

    [createPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("database"), payer.publicKey.toBuffer(), Buffer.from(name)],
      program.programId
    );
  })

  it('Create database', async () => {
    tx = await program.methods
      .createDatabase(name, data)
      .accounts({
        owner: payer.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc({commitment: "confirmed"})

    const database = await program.account.myDatabase.fetch(createPDA)
    expect(database.name).toEqual(name)
    expect(database.data).toEqual([data])
    expect(database.owner).toEqual(payer.publicKey)
  })

  it('Update database', async () => {
    const tx1 = await program.methods
      .updateDatabase(name, data2)
      .accounts({
        owner: payer.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc({commitment: "confirmed"})

    console.log(tx, tx1);
    
    const database = await program.account.myDatabase.fetch(createPDA)
    expect(database.name).toEqual(name)
    expect(database.data).toEqual([data, data2])
    expect(database.owner).toEqual(payer.publicKey)
  })

  it('Update database by any', async () => {
    const tx1 = await program.methods
      .updateByAny(name, data2)
      .accounts({
        signer: newPublicKey,
        owner: payer.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc({commitment: "confirmed"})

      const database = await program.account.myDatabase.fetch(createPDA)
  })

})

I am getting error for Update database by any:
Signature verification failed.
    Missing signature for public key [`D129zGH15L2EnUwaHdC6H7sYEKUp4yeUzCC5YWCwXMJo`].

I get that I am missing something in both lib.rs and test which I am not aware about.
Could someone help?
